# Use Clob in Spring restful service response

Tags: spring, rest, clob

I have created a class where I am using java.sql.clob field and I am getting its values from Oracle DB. When I am trying to send this class object in response entity in Spring restful services. I am getting error mentioned below.

> HTTP Status 500 - Could not write content: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: ClassName["FieldName"]->oracle.sql.CLOB["dbaccess"]->oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection["wrapper"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: ClassName["FieldName"]->oracle.sql.CLOB["dbaccess"]->oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection["wrapper"])

How I can resolve this issue